# Memory aligned QVector().data()

Tags: qt, qt5, vectorization, memory-alignment, auto-vectorization

I'm writing a program using Qt5, and I need to allocate a `QVector <float>` having its `data()` pointer 32-byte aligned.

Is there anyway I could do this without modifying the Qt library itself?

My code looks something like this:

```
QVector <float> vec;
vec.resize(n);
float *wricker_ptr = wricker.data(); // this should be 32-byte aligned
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    wricker_ptr[i] = /* some computed value */;
}
```

I'm using Intel's C++ Compiler.

Comment: btw: I found this 5-years-old [thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36090-Memory-aligned-QVector()-data()) , describing my exact problem, but it didn't contain an answer.

Comment: No, there's no way of doing it with `QVector`. Not that you need to - in this case, using `std::vector` with a custom allocator, such as [`aligned_allocator`](https://gist.github.com/donny-dont/1471329) is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind:

1. **Forget it:** use `std::vector` and a suitable allocator. `QVector`'s data payload is allocated with `alignof(T)`.¹
2. The 32 byte alignment smells of SIMD processing, so you could use a `QVector<__m256i>` or similar and `reinterpret_cast` in and out.

¹ not entirely true, see http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/22326/focus=22596